# Which pseudo random number generator algorithm does java.util.Random in Java 8 use?

Tags: random, java-8

I'm trying to find out exactly how java.util.Random in java 8 generates its random numbers, more specifically the algorithm behind it. All I keep seeing is how to generate random numbers in java 8 and not the driving forces behind it.

If you could point me to any documentation regarding the PRNG that java.util.Random uses that would be perfect.

Also in case its been done already, is there a way of replicating the output of java.util.Random in python?
A Quick test using a seed of 5 and int range of 0 to 100 gives different results to pythons random module

Comment: [Class Random](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Random.html): "The class uses a 48-bit seed, which is modified using a linear congruential formula. (See Donald Knuth, *The Art of Computer Programming*, *Volume 2*, Section 3.2.1.) "

Answer (score 1):

Quoting [Java docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Random.html):

> An instance of this class is used to generate a stream of pseudorandom numbers. The class uses a 48-bit seed, which is modified using a linear congruential formula. (See Donald Knuth, The Art of Computer Programming, Volume 2, Section 3.2.1.)

So it seems that a [Linear congruential generator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_congruential_generator) with a 48bit seed is used.

I do not have access to the mentioned book, but I would guess it gives more detailled information.

Comment: Amazon has the part online:
https://www.amazon.com/Art-Computer-Programming-Seminumerical-Algorithms/dp/0201896842?asin=B01AY4ZHKE&revisionId=&format=4&depth=1